# Spark Streaming job behaves like a batch

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm trying to run a Spark Streaming job to read messages from Kafka. For testing I insert into Kafka a couple of gigabytes of messages and then launch the streaming job (python).

```
from spark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("spark://master1:7077,master2:7077,master3:7077")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ["test_topic"], {"metadata.broker.list": "kafka1:9092,kafka2:9092,kafka3:9092", "auto.offset.reset": "smallest"})

directKafkaStream.count().pprint()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I would expect the job to update me every second with messages counted so far (streaming). However the job counts all messages in the queue (whatever time it takes) and only after all messages are counted, I see an update (batch).

Please, could anyone tell me what have I missed here.

**UPDATE**:
What I was expecting to see:

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2016-01-28 16:23:42
-------------------------------------------
1000000

-------------------------------------------
Time: 2016-01-28 16:23:43
-------------------------------------------
10000000
```

What I'm actually seeing:

```
16/01/28 16:25:10 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1453994710000 ms
16/01/28 16:25:11 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1453994711000 ms
16/01/28 16:25:12 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1453994712000 ms
16/01/28 16:25:13 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1453994713000 ms
16/01/28 16:25:14 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1453994714000 ms
16/01/28 16:25:15 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1453994715000 ms
16/01/28 16:25:16 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1453994716000 ms
...
```

Comment: How are you submitting your Job and where are you seeing these logs?

Comment: spark-submit --jars spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.5.2.jar ./spark_streaming_kafka.py.
I see those logs on stdout

Comment: what do you see in your Spark--UI